# can we delete the branch after merging the changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, git-branch, branching-strategy

We are using BitBucket integrated with Jira and Bamboo as part of our development process. I really like the idea of navigating from Jira to Bitbucket, able to see the pull request status on Jira, and build information on Jira. Also able to create a feature/bugfix branch directly from jira against a user story.
But I am not a big fan of keeping the branches even after merging the feature branch to the main branch.
Is there a way wherein I can delete the feature branch after merging the changes but yet have some details on the Jira regarding this. In our process we do not delete the feature branches and I am afraid that the remote branches will be bloating around after some time. What other options do I have?

Comment: But since in Jira there is a link to merged PR from that branch which is basically the same commit, why would you need another link to a branch?

Answer (score 0):

Locally: `git branch -d branch-name`

Remotely: `git push whatever-remote :branch-name`

Comment: I know to delete the branch. But deleting the branch will also remove the pointer/marker from jira from where I could see the branch information.

Comment: Maybe an overkill but have you considered using another repo where you get rid of those branches and keep them only on the repo related to jira?

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this to delete remote branch
`$ git push origin --delete <branch_name>`

Comment: I know how to delete the remote branch but then I will loose the branch information from Jira.

Comment: Update Jira with build number so that you can keep track of work. In my company we use Octapus. Once the build is ready to be deployed to prod we publish that build number in the Jira, at that point you can delete branch.